# Trying to convert txt.file with edges into edgelist

Tags: python, type-conversion, networkx

I have a txt. -file which is of this format:

```
0   61
0   33344
0   33412
0   36114
0   37320
0   37769
0   37924
```

This is in fact a list of edges for a network which I want to convert into the following

```
elist = [(0,61), (0,33344), (0,33412), (0,36114), (0,37320), (0,37769), (0,37924)]
```

My idea was the following:

```
import csv

data = open("path_to_file.txt", 'r')
reader = csv.reader(data)
allRows = [tuple(row) for row in reader]
```

The problem is that I receive this:

```
[('0\t61',), ('0\t33344',), ('0\t33412',), ('0\t36114',), ('0\t37320',), ('0\t37769',), ('0\t37924',)]
```

How can we fix this?

Comment: You need to specify the delimiter as tabs rather than commas; `csv.reader(data, delimiter='\t')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import csv

data = open("path_to_file.txt", 'r')
reader = csv.reader(data)
allRows = [tuple(row.split('\t')) for row in reader]
```

You were close. And there's almost certainly another way to have `csv` split on tabs instead of commas if you'd rather go that route.

EDIT: as @roganjosh said, you could just do

```
import csv

data = open("path_to_file.txt", 'r')
reader = csv.reader(data, delimiter='\t'))
allRows = [tuple(row) for row in reader]
```

Comment: You should really show the way to specify this in the reader rather than showing how to fix the broken output with another full pass of all the data.

Answer (score 1):

The other posters had mentioned that you can just use the escape code `\t` as a delimiter in `csv.reader()` to parse out the extra rows. This is true, but it appears from your file that your delimiter is actually four spaces instead of a single tab. So, this will not work.

If you print out `[row for row in reader]`, you find that the separation between adjacent elements is not being preserved:

```
 [['0   61'],
 ['0   33344'],
 ['0   33412'],
 ['0   36114'],
 ['0   37320'],
 ['0   37769'],
 ['0   37924']]
```

Therefore, efforts made to turn this into a tuple will fail, as there is only one `str` element per row. So then, each `row` in `reader` is a single element `list`. Calling `row[0]` will give you the actual string value: `'0   61'`.

We then use `.split()` to create *two* elements from this string:

```
In [47]: '0   61'.split()
Out[47]: ['0', '61']
```

Now, we can use `map` to create integers from these two new strings:

```
In [49]: map(int,'0   61'.split())
Out[49]: [0, 61]
```

Then, we convert to a tuple and append to a list, like you did above, and we have a working solution.

```
data = open("path_to_file.txt", 'r')
reader = csv.reader(data)
allRows = [tuple(map(int,row[0].split())) for row in reader]

In [43]: allRows
Out[43]:
[(0, 61),
 (0, 33344),
 (0, 33412),
 (0, 36114),
 (0, 37320),
 (0, 37769),
 (0, 37924)]
```

Comment: Try to post more than just code. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Comment: @Martin:   Updated.